# Changing the correct object in the text file

Tags: python, dictionary, text, task

Task:
If the user chooses ‘vm’ to view the tasks that are assigned to them, only display all the tasks that have been assigned to the user that is currently logged-in in a user-friendly, easy to read manner. Make sure that each task is displayed with a corresponding number which can be used to identify the task. Allow the user to select either a specific task by entering a number or input ‘-1’ to return to the main menu. If the user selects a specific task, they should be able to choose to either mark the task as complete or edit the task. If the user chooses to mark a task as complete, the ‘Yes’/’No’ value that describes whether the task has been completed or not should be changed to ‘Yes’. When the user chooses to edit a task, the username of the person to whom the task is assigned or the due date of the task can be edited. The task can only be edited if it has not yet been completed.

```
def view_more():
        username = input("Please enter the username which you want to view the tasks for?\n")
        num_task = 0     
        view_more = open('tasks.txt', 'r')
        for row in view_more:
                field = row.strip().split(",")
                num_task += 1
                if username == field[0]:
                        print("Task Number: " + str(num_task) + "\nUsername: " + field[0] + "\nTitle: " + field[1] + "\nDescription: " + field[2] + "\nDue Date: " + field[3] + "\nCompleted: " + field[4] + "\n")

        editTask = input("Would you like to edit a task? (Edit) or return to the menu? (-1)\n")
        if editTask == "Edit":
            taskNum = int(input("Please enter the Task number?\n"))
            taskNum = taskNum - 1
            file = open('tasks.txt', 'r')
            taskFile = file.readlines()
            for line in taskFile:
                print(taskFile[taskNum] + "\n")
                break

            taskComplete = input("Has this task been completed?\n")
            if taskComplete == "Yes":
                userTask = taskFile[taskNum].strip().split(",")
                userTask[4] = "Yes"
                print(userTask)

            elif taskComplete == "No":
                userTask = taskFile[taskNum].strip().split(",")
                userTask[4] = "No"
                file.write(userTask[4])

        elif editTask == "-1":
            displayMenu()

view_more()
```

Question:
How would I now go about changing the 'No' to a 'Yes' in the text file? I've managed to read the text file and change what's needed in the list and prints out what I want but I know need to change it in the text file too. Thanks any help would greatly be appreciated.

Tasks Text File:

```
admin,test,test,29/03/2020,No
admin,test2,test2,01/04/2020,No
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, replace selected task with user input:

`new_state = taskFile[taskNum].strip().replace(userTask[4], taskComplete)`

Update your file data with new task:

`updated_string = view_more.replace(taskFile[taskNum].strip(), new_state)`

Write your updated data to file:

```
with open('tasks.txt', 'w') as f:
   f.write(updated_string)
```

```py
def view_more():
    username = input("Please enter the username which you want to view the tasks for?\n")
    num_task = 0
    with open('tasks.txt', 'r') as f:
        view_more = f.read()
    for row in view_more:
            field = row.strip().split(",")
            num_task += 1
            if username == field[0]:
                    print("Task Number: " + str(num_task) + "\nUsername: " + field[0] + "\nTitle: " + field[1] + "\nDescription: " + field[2] + "\nDue Date: " + field[3] + "\nCompleted: " + field[4] + "\n")

    editTask = input("Would you like to edit a task? (Edit) or return to the menu? (-1)\n")

    def _edit_file(taskComplete):
        userTask = taskFile[taskNum].strip().split(",")
        new_state = taskFile[taskNum].strip().replace(userTask[4], taskComplete)
        print(new_state)
        updated_string = view_more.replace(taskFile[taskNum].strip(), new_state)
        with open('tasks.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(updated_string)

    if editTask == "Edit":
        taskNum = int(input("Please enter the Task number?\n"))
        taskNum = taskNum - 1
        with open('tasks.txt', 'r') as file:
            taskFile = file.readlines()
        for line in taskFile:
            print(taskFile[taskNum] + "\n")
            break

        taskComplete = input("Has this task been completed?\n")
        if taskComplete == "Yes":
            _edit_file(taskComplete)

        elif taskComplete == "No":
            _edit_file(taskComplete)

    elif editTask == "-1":
        displayMenu()

view_more()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update this line:**

```
updated_string = view_more.replace(taskFile[taskNum].strip(), new_state)
```

**with this :**

```
updated_string = view_more.read().replace(taskFile[taskNum].strip(), new_state)
```